How to replicate Weather on WatchOS


Weather app on apple watch has this button at top right that can change the viewing mode between Conditions, Temperature, Precipitation, etc. What kind of SwiftUI is this? Is this a custom UI with a button?
ChatGPT tells me to use SegmentedPickerStyle, which is not available in WatchOS
Picker("View", selection: $selectedView) {
    Text("Conditions").tag("Conditions")
    Text("Temperature").tag("Temperature")
    Text("Precipitation").tag("Precipitation")
}.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())


It could be a switch for every selectedView the second photo is just a Menu

You might need to make a custom UI using your own buttons to achieve this.

I was able to replicate as below as a child of navigationStack
struct Example: View {
    @State private var showSheet = false
    var body: some View {
        // ...
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarTrailing) {
                Button {
                    showSheet.toggle()
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "ellipsis")
                }
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
            List {
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
}


I managed to get close to the weather App interface by using a combination of InlinePickerStyle() presented inside a Form in a sheet.
To get the button placements to show up you also need to embed your tabView in a NavigationStack.
This assumes you are building for watchOS 10 as a target.
enum Tabs: String, CaseIterable, Identifiable {
    
    case one = "Cold"
    case two = "Warm"
    case three = "Hot"
    
    var id: Self { self }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selected = Tabs.one
    @State var sheetIsPresented = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            TabView(selection: $selected) {
                ForEach(Tabs.allCases) { item in
                    Text("\(item.rawValue) tab")
                }
            }
            .tabViewStyle(.verticalPage)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarTrailing) {
                    Button {
                        sheetIsPresented = true
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "thermometer.medium")
                            
                    }
                    .foregroundStyle(.white)
                }
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $sheetIsPresented, content: {
            Form {
                Picker("View", selection: $selected) {
                    ForEach(Tabs.allCases) { item in
                        Text(item.rawValue)
                    }
                }
                .pickerStyle(InlinePickerStyle())
                .onChange(of: selected) {
                    sheetIsPresented = false
                }

          }
        })
    }
}

